# Sorting a JSON response in Angular5 using typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am making an API call from Angular 5, the response is coming in below format.

```
let ob = {   "metadata":{
      "lastSyncTime":"2000-11-21T16:07:53",
      "dataFromDB":true
   },
   "allocationReports":[ 
      {
         "allocatedUserCount":130,
         "healthGoalName":"Feel Happier"
      },
  
      {
         "allocatedUserCount":150,
         "healthGoalName":"Quit Smoking"
      },
      {
         "allocatedUserCount":100,
         "healthGoalName":"Eat Healthier"
      }
   ],
   "overall":{
      "usersWithGoalCount":0,
      "registeredCount":500,
      "eligibleCount":280
   }
}
```

I need to transform this data into a list of lists(or Array of Arrays) so that I can plot multiple donut charts on this data. I have tried with multiple methods like using .map, but getting all the values in single list. How can I build the data in below format.

The required format is : [Array should be sorted.]

```
[ 
 [
  { "x": "Eat Healthier", "y": 100 },
  { "x": "Total registered", "y": 500 } 
 ],
 [
  { "x": "Feel Happier", "y": 130 },
  { "x": "Total registered", "y": 500 } 
 ],
 [
  { "x": "Quit Smoking", "y": 150 },
  { "x": "Total registered", "y": 500 } 
 ]
]
```

I have written below code.

```
r=ob.allocationReports.map(o=>{return [{x:o.healthGoalName,y:o.allocatedUserCount},{x: "Total registered", y: ob.overall.registeredCount }]})
```

But the result I am getting is not sorted. How can I sort this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort array of objects by string property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value)

Comment: Yes.. this works. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this it will sort them in **ascending** order

```js
ob={"metadata":{ "lastSyncTime":"2000-11-21T16:07:53", "dataFromDB":true }, "allocationReports":[ { "allocatedUserCount":130, "healthGoalName":"Feel Happier" },     { "allocatedUserCount":100, "healthGoalName":"Eat Healthier" },{ "allocatedUserCount":150, "healthGoalName":"Quit Smoking" } ], "overall":{ "usersWithGoalCount":0, "registeredCount":500, "eligibleCount":280 } }
r=ob.allocationReports.map(o=>{return [{x:o.healthGoalName,y:o.allocatedUserCount},{x: "Total registered", y: ob.overall.registeredCount }]}).sort((a,b)=>a[0].y-b[0].y)
console.log(r)
```